# PIP Install file not found on Linux Servers

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to install PIP on Ubuntu 20.04.02 but apparently the command `sudo apt install python3-pip`is throwing me to a broken destiny.

Basically it can't find the files it's looking for, and it won't find for sure because the file doesnt exist.

Example:

`$ sudo apt install python3-pip`

`...`

`Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

`$ Y`

`...`

`Not found something...`
`...`

`Not found something else...`

`...`

`E: Failed to find http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.8/libpython3.8-dev_3.8.5-1~20.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found`

`Impossible to find some files, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix --missing?`

I translated it, so maybe it is not exactly how it is supposed to be in english

If you access http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.8/ then you can see that the file PIP install is looking for doesnt exist (libpython3.8-dev_3.8.5-1~20.04.2_amd64.deb)

WHy is that? How can I install PIP on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Ubuntu 20.04.02 as well and there pip already came installed! Specifically for python3.8 and python3.9.

When I want to install a specific library I just run that following command

```sh
python3.8 -m pip install module_name_here
```

When I don't specify `python3.8`, (and just write `python`) it defaults to python 2.7.1 on my rig and that indeed doesn't have pip installed for some reason, but it looks like you want to install pip on python3.8.

Comment: @mateusvl Have you tried this? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py (specifically running `$ python3.8 get-pip.py`)

Comment: You are leading them further onto the wrong path. They should just figure out how to solve the problem they are actually asking about.